# Detecting an approaching object

Tags: python, c++, opencv, object-detection

I read [this](https://shaneormonde.wordpress.com/2014/01/25/webcam-laser-rangefinder/) blog post where he uses a Laser and a Webcam to estimated the distance of the cardboard from the Webcam.

I had another idea about that. I don't want to calculate the distance from the webcam.

I want to check if an object is approaching the webcam. The algorithm, according to me, will be something like:

1. Detect the object in the webcam feed.
2. If the object is approaching the webcam it'll grow larger and larger in the video feed.
3. Use this data for further calculations.

Since I want to detect random objects, I am using the `findContours()` method to find the contours in the video feed. Using that, I will at least have the outlines of the objects in the video feed. The source code is:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

vid=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
ans, instant=vid.read()
average=np.float32(instant)
cv2.accumulateWeighted(instant, average, 0.01)
background=cv2.convertScaleAbs(average)

while(1):
    _,f=vid.read()
    imgray=cv2.cvtColor(f, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    ret, thresh=cv2.threshold(imgray,127,255,0)
    diff=cv2.absdiff(f, background)
    cv2.imshow("input", f)
    cv2.imshow("Difference", diff)
    if cv2.waitKey(5)==27:
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The output is:

[image]

I am stuck here. I have the contours stored in an array. What do I do with it when the size increases? How do I proceed?

Comment: just to trigger your curiousity, there's even an [acoustical way](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/groups/cue/publications/GuptaSoundWaveCHI2012.pdf) to do this ;)

Answer (score 4):

One trouble here is recognising and differentiating the moving objects from other stuff in the video feed. An approach might be to let the camera 'learn' what the background looks like with no object. Then you can constantly compare its input against this background. One way to get the background is to use a running average.

Any difference greater than a small threshold means there is a moving object. If you constantly display this difference, you basically have a motion tracker. The size of the objects is simply the sum of all the non-zero (thresholded) pixels, or their bounding rectangles. You can track this size and use it to guess whether the object is moving closer or further. Morphological operations can help group the contours into one cohesive object.

Since it will be tracking ANY movement, if there are two objects, they will be counted together. Here is where you can use the contours to find and track individual objects, e.g. using the contour bounds or centroids. You could also possibly separate them by colour.

Here are some results using this strategy (the grey blob is my hand):

[image: My hand moving towards the camera]

[image: My hand moving away from the camera]

It actually did a fairly good job of guessing which way my hand was moving.

Code:

```python
import cv2
import numpy as np

AVERAGE_ALPHA      = 0.2         # 0-1 where 0 never adapts, and 1 instantly adapts
MOVEMENT_THRESHOLD = 30          # Lower values pick up more movement
REDUCED_SIZE       = (400, 600)
MORPH_KERNEL       = np.ones((10, 10), np.uint8)

def reduce_image(input_image):
    """Make the image easier to deal with."""
    reduced = cv2.resize(input_image, REDUCED_SIZE) 
    reduced = cv2.cvtColor(reduced, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    return reduced

# Initialise
vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
average = None

old_sizes = np.zeros(20)
size_update_index = 0

while (True):
    got_frame, frame = vid.read()

    if got_frame:
        # Reduce image
        reduced = reduce_image(frame)
        if average is None: average = np.float32(reduced)

        # Get background
        cv2.accumulateWeighted(reduced, average, AVERAGE_ALPHA) 
        background = cv2.convertScaleAbs(average)

        # Get thresholded difference image
        movement     = cv2.absdiff(reduced, background)
        _, threshold = cv2.threshold(movement, MOVEMENT_THRESHOLD, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

        # Apply morphology to help find object
        dilated = cv2.dilate(threshold, MORPH_KERNEL, iterations=10)
        closed  = cv2.morphologyEx(dilated, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, MORPH_KERNEL)

        # Get contours
        contours, _ = cv2.findContours(closed, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        cv2.drawContours(closed, contours, -1, (150, 150, 150), -1)

        # Find biggest bounding rectangle
        areas = [cv2.contourArea(c) for c in contours]
        if (areas != list()):
            max_index = np.argmax(areas)
            max_cont  = contours[max_index]

            x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(max_cont)
            cv2.rectangle(closed, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 255, 255), 5)

            # Guess movement direction
            size = w*h
            if size > old_sizes.mean():
                print "Towards"
            else:
                print "Away"

            # Update object size 
            old_sizes[size_update_index] = size
            size_update_index += 1
            if (size_update_index) >= len(old_sizes): size_update_index = 0

        # Display image
        cv2.imshow('RaptorVision', closed)
```

Obviously this needs more work in terms of identifying, selecting and tracking the objects etc (at the moment it does horribly if there is something else moving in the background). There are also many parameters to vary and tweak (the ones set are what worked well for my system). I'll leave that up to you though.

Some links:

[background extraction](http://opencvpython.blogspot.com/2012/07/background-extraction-using-running.html)

[motion tracking](http://derek.simkowiak.net/motion-tracking-with-python/)

If you want to get a bit more high-tech with the background removal, have a look here:

[wallflower](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/jckrumm/Publications/WallFlower/final%20published.pdf)

Comment: So essentially the program will require some time to initialise and then (with suitable modifications) be able to track objects in front of the background? Wow! :)

Comment: In theory :) hopefully the required modifications won't be too finicky…

Comment: Okay, so I implemented the `accumulateWeight()` function. I am capturing the background. That's the initialisation. What do I do next? I'll update the source code and the images in the question. How do I calculate the difference?

Comment: openCV has an absdiff function which should do the trick. Unfortunately I'm at work so can't test it :( Updated the answer though.

Comment: PS I had intended that the background be updated regularly, so it should be inside your loop. The idea is that anything static fades away.

Comment: Calculating it in a loop is just giving me a black image and nothing more. Although initially it was showing the difference but the program does need updation of the background image.

Comment: Well I guess outside the loop works, if the webcam isn't going to be moving. It should update at least semi-regularly though, to account for things like changes in ambient light.

Comment: You will check it out, yes? Will wait for the updated answer. I hope you are able to update the background too. :/

Comment: I updated my answer, this is as far as I go however. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. :)

One problem though. I can't see anything in the RaptorVision window. Any idea where it might be going wrong?

Comment: Did you copy my code exactly? Sorry I have no idea, it works for me… Try playing with the parameters..

Comment: Yes I did, just copied and pasted it. I'll try to do that.

Comment: Did you have any luck?

Comment: No. Had my system changed. Will install and try again.

Comment: Yes, the problem is continuing. Any suggestions/changes that you have in mind?

Comment: Have you tried displaying all the intermediate stages, e.g. reduced, background, movement etc to try see at what stage it goes black?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> Detect the object in the webcam feed.
> If the object is approaching the webcam it'll grow larger and larger in the video feed.
> Use this data for further calculations.
> ```

Good idea.
If you want to use the contour detection approach, you could do it the following way:

1. You have a series of Images I1, I2, ... In
2. Do a contour detection on each one. C1, C2, ..., Cn (Contour is a set of points in OpenCV)
3. Take a large enough sample on your Image i and i+1: S_i \leq C_i, i \in 1...n
4. Check for all points in your sample for the nearest point on i+1. Then you trajectorys for all your points.
5. Check if this trajectorys point mostly outwards (tricky part ;)
6. If they appear outwards for a suffiecent number of frames your contour got bigger.

Alternative you could try to prune the points that are not part of the correct contour and work with a covering rectangle. It's very easy to check the size that way, but i don't knwo how easy it will be to choose the "correct" points.

Comment: 5. is tricky indeed! One trouble is if the object is much bigger than the background. In that case the contours may form around a piece of background, which would shrink as the object got bigger.

Comment: @PokeyMcPokerson: you can invert a contour that touches more than 30%-60% of the border

Comment: What if the object doesn't fit in the screen? Then it will also be touching the border.